# Build failed running AudioKit cookbook with Xcode 13.1 - Cannot find 'kDynamicsProcessorParam_OverallGainn' in scope

Tags: audiokit

Cloned repository of [Audiokit](https://github.com/AudioKit/Cookbook) and builded with last nobeta version of XCode 13.1 and get this error:

```
Cannot find 'kDynamicsProcessorParam_OverallGainn' in scope
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to the latest AudioKit, this is fixed.

Comment: Yes, updating the Package from 2.2.1(repo) to 2.2.2 the issue disappears